# Using PDO in Zephir

Tags: zephir

As part of my experiments with Zephir I am currently trying to use PHP PDO to access a MySQL database.  For starters I found that a relatively innocuous

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbn;","user","pwd");
```

when translated and used in Zephir

```
var dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbn;","user","pwd");
```

had Zephir throwing up an exception

```
var dbh = new PDO
------------^
```

which by dint of some searching I resolved - new is a reserved word in Zephir and must be replaced with $new.

```
var dbh = $new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbn;","user","pwd");
```

which promptly produced

```
var dbh = $new PDO(
-----------------^
```

which I resolved when I realized that I had to explicitly tell Zephir to use the PDO name space

```
use \PDO;
var dbh = $new \PDO::PDO(
```

Now, with

```
var dbh = $new \PDO::PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbn","user","pwd");
```

I get

```
var dbh = $new \PDO::PDO(...,"user","pwd");
---------------------------------------------^
```

which makes little sense to me.

From what I can tell Zephir is still too young to be considered for a full port of a working PHP prototype.  However, it looks like it is good enough to be used to port some of the more CPU intensive bits of a PHP application but its documentation is lacking. For instance, nowhere does it state in the docs that the right way to use an array is

```
array myArray;
 let myArray = [1,2,...];
```

Miss out the first list and the compiler complains about not being able to mutate.

With my current PDO problem there is a clearly something else that is wrong - how can I find what it might be?

Comment: Dang, we really need a Zephir guy in SO to answer these Zephir questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `var` keyword in zephir is for variable declarations.
If you assign a "simple" value like a string or an array,
it will work.

The problem with your example is that `new PDO(<arguments>)` is an expression,
where the `var` operator is not the right choice.
So what you want is to assign a value.

Variables are by default immutable. (see zephir-lang.com)
That's why you need to use the `let` operator, which makes them immutable
and is able to resolve expressions.

So you need to use `var` and `let`
like `var dbh; let dbh = new \PDO(<arguments>);`

And if you do it that way, it works :)